# 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'LANGUAGE_CODE'

Tags: django-cms, django-wsgi

When I disable
`cms.middleware.multilingual.MultilingualURLMiddleware`

I have
Caught an exception while rendering `'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'LANGUAGE_CODE'`
when edit pages, or use `{% show_menu_below_id %}` tag.

I don't need lang prefix please, help me disable this stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

issue:
http://github.com/divio/django-cms/issues/issue/424#issue/424/comment/188388

```
use "lang = get_language()" in menu pool
```

Answer (score 8):

add `'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware'` to `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES`